# How to create a hole on a ground in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a game like Color Hole. I've created a ground and a 3d cylinder. I want this cylinder act like a hole instead of a solid cylinder. Is there any opinion how can I do this without using Blender or etc?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you attach a script to the "hole" object, you could detect other objects entering in OnColliderEnter().  Then, using the OnColliderStay() method, you could move them downwards "through" the hole, then destroy them (or whatever you want to happen when they pass through the hole).

It's kind of a hacky solution, but it would work if you're unable make a custom asset.  It's not going to give you physics engine interaction though, so making the object tumble realistically through the hole will be more effort than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

For modeling and mesh prototyping within unity there are very cool assets, such as [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/umodeler-80868), or [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/archimatix-pro-59733).
The most affordable of the solutions of course is to import the model you want as wanted from your modeling program.

It would expected to be possible with pro-builder (modeling tool integrated in unity). However its not.

Window->PackageManager->Probuilder
Then you need to enable the experimental features:
Edit->Preferences->ProBuilder

[image]

Then there is a tool that its supposed to make union, instersection and substraction of meshes:

[image]

However it does not work and at least for what I tried, I obtain this error **always**:

StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack overflow.
UnityEngine.ProBuilder.Csg.Plane.SplitPolygon

(Unity version 2018.4.12). Maybe it can be checked if there is an issue with the unity version and if the pro-builder approach migh work in others.

Comment: I've tried to make it with Probuilder. However, it doesn't allow me to select "Experimental features enabled" box. The box is always empty not matter how many times I click on it.

Comment: so strange. Try search in Tools->Experimental...maybe in later unity versions its already there...Anyhow the experimental tool does not seem to work so no big deal